# Hiding a select in a div depending of radio

Tags: jquery

Let's see if you can help me: I have this html:

```
<div class="store">
    <input type="radio" name="storename" id="store1" />
    <select name="time_availability">
        <option value="1pm">01:00 pm</option>
        <option value="2pm">02:00 pm</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="store">
    <input type="radio" name="storename" id="store1" />
    <select name="time_availability">
        <option value="1pm">01:00 pm</option>
        <option value="2pm">02:00 pm</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="store">
    <input type="radio" name="storename" id="store1" />
    <select name="time_availability">
        <option value="1pm">01:00 pm</option>
        <option value="2pm">02:00 pm</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

By default, each select inside div class "store" keeps hide and only when check a radio, the select which comes immediately after that radio is displayed while others keep hidden, so I did this:

```
$('input[name="storename"]:radio').change(function() {
    $(this).parents('.store').find('select').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

My problem: when I check another radio option, the previously select still appearing instead of hiding previous select and display the respective select that comes right after the radio I clicked? I don't know if I was clear...

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You've got to hide the other `select` before showing yours:

```
$('input[name="storename"]:radio').change(function() {
    $(".store select").fadeOut("fast"); //hide others
    $(this).parent('.store').find('select').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zyt9y1b7/

Answer (score 0):

You should first hide the select fields that are visible, or they will still be displayed. I would use something like the following javascript:

```
$('input[name="storename"]').click(function() {
    $('select[name="time_availability"]').hide();
    $(this).siblings('select').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

You can see a working demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/2Lm63cjy/